# Putting an SSD with Win 7 in a new Win 8 laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, uefi

I have an older laptop (a TP E420) with a 64GB SSD running Win 7 Home Premium. Say I buy a new Windows 8 laptop that doesn't have an SSD. Can I just take the HDD out and swap my extant SSD in, and have it boot up to Win 7 and everything works fine? I'm assuming not, but exactly why not?

Answer (score 0):

It **might** work, but it's very likely that you will run into problems.

1. Your windows 8 laptop is most likely booting in UEFI mode.  With secure boot enabled.  Your windows 7 laptop seems to support UEFI, but it's not sure if windows 7 was installed on it in UEFI or legacy mode.  Legacy was the default in most cases.  If it was in legacy mode then you should be able to switch your new laptop from UEFI to legacy mode, if not you won't be able to boot the windows 7 disk.  (at the office we have 2 types of windows 8 machines (bot based on a Z2760 atom CPU) that only offer UEFI mode, not legacy)
2. If you can make it boot, then you'll probably find plenty of devices that won't be supported.  You will have to find the drivers for it (if they do exist for windows 7).
3. If you can make it work, it's almost sure that it's not legal.  The windows 7 license on the E420 is probably an OEM version, you're not allowed to move that license to another machine.  It will probably ask for activation too, and it's possible that you won't be able to activate it.